# AngularJS: render table columns before content is received

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I make AngularJS render table columns correctly before the intended content for them is received?

I'm using `ng-if` to show the content, since I need different elements depending on the value that I get back from an API call, see below. This is the only reason for not using ng-bind, which I assume would be a more legitimate solution.

```
<td ng-if="someArray.length > 0"><a ng-href="someLink">Yes</a></td>
<td ng-if="someArray.length == 0">No</td>
```

Using this, due to obvious reasons the particular column is not shown at all while `someArray` is not initiated. I could check for `undefined` in the second `ng-if`, but I would rather have the column be completely empty while waiting for a value.
I am still quite new to AngularJS and I assume that there is a best-practice here.

Comment: Why don't you move the condition to the content of the `<td>`, i.e. `<td><a ng-if="someArray.length > 0">Yes</a><span ng-if="someArray.length == 0">No</span></td>`?

Comment: How would you know how much to render if you don't have access to the data yet? Anyway you could place the ng-if statement to an element inside the table cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if in internal dom elements

```
<td>
  <a ng-if="someArray.length > 0" ng-href="someLink">Yes</a>
  <p ng-if="someArray.length == 0">NO</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the ng-if into the elements within the td:

```
<td>
    <a ng-if="someArray.length > 0" ng-href="someLink">Yes</a>
    <span ng-if="someArray.length == 0">No</span>
</td>
```